# Linking iOS In-App Subscription to MySQL database

Tags: ios, mysql, in-app-subscription

I have followed some tutorials on implementing In-App purchases and subscriptions for iOS (especially Ray Wenderlich) but I have doubts on how to integrate our iOS app with our website so that if someone subscribes to the app they can access the content on the web as well.

Our website and app offer access to videos. All subscribers have access to all videos. Our web works with PHP and MySQL. When someone subscribes on the web, a record for their account is created in our MySQL database and they are flagged as subscribers so that they can access the content.

We want to implement in-app subscription in our app, but we need for a record to be created in our database when the subscription takes place.

The question is, should we do this upon receipt validation (we'll be doing this in PHP)? Also, is there a way to know when a user unsubscribes through iOS so that the database can be updated accordingly?

Our closest example of how we would like it to work is Gaia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should we do this upon receipt validation?

Yes, you should wait until you validate the receipt to mark the subscription as active for the user.

> Is there a way to know when a user unsubscribes through iOS so that
>   the database can be updated accordingly?

The correct way to implement this is to store the entire IAP receipt on your server and periodically refresh it with Apple to get the current subscription status. Just because somebody started a subscription doesn't mean it will still be active the next time you check it (e.g. they may have turned off auto-renew or been issued a refund).

This blog posts explains some of the nuances in further detail: [iOS Subscriptions Are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to know when a user unsubscribes through iOS so that
>   the database can be updated accordingly?

Use status update notification.

> A statusUpdateNotification is a server-to-server notification service
>   for auto-renewable subscriptions. A notification specifies the status
>   of a subscription at the time the notification is sent.

As status update notification is not a reliable service,  Apple recommend to use this in combination of other method such as polling the *verifyreceipt* end point. creating a scheduler in server will be best option along with notification.